# Extension method call throwing fatal error

Tags: extensions, error

I'm using an extension for marketing emails on a magento site.

On certain pages a phtml file is called that uses some javascript. For the js to get rendered an if statement has to pass

```
   if(Mage::helper('connector')->getPageTrackingEnabled()) :?>
     //some js
   <?php endif; ?>
```

getPageTrackingEnabled() is a method inside data.php which checks the value of system config global variable. It looks like this:

```
   public function getPageTrackingEnabled()
{
    return (bool)Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_PAGE_TRACKING_ENABLED);
}
```

But causes this error

```
   Fatal error: Call to undefined method Dotdigitalgroup_Email_Helper_Data::getPageTrackingEnabled()
```

Any suggestions on where I should go from here. I've done the done the cache, disabled compilation and tried calling the method differently but with no luck unfortunately

EDIT
config.xml

```
   <helpers>
        <connector>
            <class>Dotdigitalgroup_Email_Helper</class>
        </connector>
    </helpers>
```

Comment: Can you show how requesting a helper called connector resolves to the helper in the error message?

Comment: I added part of the config which shows the connector helper with it's class. If this is not what you mean can you be more specific. Thanks for the repsonse

Comment: In case the error is not clear to you, it doesn't respond with a file or directory name but instead the class name.

Comment: Check if the correct `Dotdigitalgroup_Email_Helper_Data` is used. If you have one in the `community` codepool and one in the `local` codepool the one from `local` will be used.

Comment: Spot on Marius. I thought I had removed all of the original extension before installing the update but a folder in local managed to slip through. Thanks very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a temporary solution I've done an include inside the phtml file that gets called on the page.

```
    $site_url =  Mage::getBaseDir(); 
    include($site_url . '/app/code/community/Dotdigitalgroup/Email/Helper/Data.php');
```

I'm not very happy with the solution so would be very welcoming of any alternative advice or even if someone could explain to me how exactly a data.php file gets rendered. This might give me a greater insight into where it could be going wrong.

---

EDIT

The problem was with some files in the local code pool that I had missed. One of them was conflicting with the new files which were in the community pool. After deleting the ones in Local the issue was resolved